# How do i update a nested value via. the API?

Tags: api, nested, shopware, shopware6

How do i update a nested value via. the API? i want to update my custom field **custom_product_fields_magento_product_id**

Request path: /api/product/f9529c4f40e94fa6ae7439f97090cc9e

Request type: PATCH

Body:

```
{
    "translated.customFields.custom_product_fields_magento_product_id" : "123"
}
```

Where am i going wrong? i can easily update product values that arent nested, like `"productNumber" : "value"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
{
    "customFields": {
        "custom_product_fields_magento_product_id":"123"
    }
}
```

The value will be automatically saved to translation, the language of which is specified in the request header or in the default language.